# Passing struct to scatter function returns an error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct, parameter-passing, scatter-plot, scatter

I am trying to scatter plot the data that was stored as struct data type.

```
scatter(1,1, ...
'ApplicationData', lin_data.ApplicationData, ...
'CData', lin_data.CData, ...
'CDataSource', lin_data.CDataSource, ...
'Jitter', lin_data.Jitter, ...
'JitterAmount', lin_data.JitterAmount, ...
'LineWidth', lin_data.LineWidth, ...
'Marker', lin_data.Marker, ...
'MarkerEdgeColor', lin_data.MarkerEdgeColor, ...
'MarkerFaceColor', lin_data.MarkerFaceColor, ...
'SizeData', lin_data.SizeData, ...
'SizeDataSource', lin_data.SizeDataSource, ...
'XData', lin_data.XData, ...
'XDataSource', lin_data.XDataSource, ...
'YData', lin_data.YData, ...
'YDataSource', lin_data.YDataSource, ...
'ZData', lin_data.ZData, ...
'ZDataSource', lin_data.ZDataSource, ...
'SelectionHandleMode', lin_data.SelectionHandleMode)
```

The above code works. However, if I pass the `lin_data` variable directly, it returns an error:

```
scatter(1,1,lin_data)

Error using double
Conversion to double from struct is not possible.

Error in datachk (line 11)
    y = full(double(x));

Error in datachk (line 9)
    y = cellfun(@datachk,x,'UniformOutput',false);

Error in scatter (line 55)
dataargs = datachk(args(1:nargs));
```

`lin_data` is a struct. Any ideas?

EDIT: It works if I use `set`, but I still don't understand why passing the struct directly doesn't work. BTW, if I use `plot` it works with passing structs as arguments

```
h = scatter(1,1);
h.set(lin_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a limitation of the `scatter` function. To validate the arguments, `scatter` calls:

```
58    dataargs = datachk(args(1:nargs));
```

where `datachk.m` simply is (for non-cell inputs)

```
11    y = full(double(x));
```

which converts the input to non-sparse double values. If you pass a struct to `scatter`, it will fail there with the error you posted in the question.
Long story short: Mathworks created `scatter` in a way, which doesn't allow for struct inputs.

To be able to pass a struct of options, you can either use the solution you already have:

```
set(h,lin_data);
```

or convert the struct to a cell array and pass the cell array:

```
c_lin_data(1,:) = fieldnames(lin_data);
c_lin_data(2,:) = struct2cell(lin_data);
scatter(1,1,c_lin_data{:});
```